# private variables of a class can be accessed from html?

Tags: typescript, angular5

I am working on angular 5, in the ts file I have a class which has a private member. I am able to access this member of an object from html. I am not understanding how is this possible. Similarly I have a readonly member which can be changed in the html

```
export class SongBrief {

    constructor(private readonly name: string, private readonly index: number) {

    }

}
```

I expected that the html page would not be able to read the private member and not modify a readonly member

Comment: Hint: JavaScript, which is what TypeScript compiles down to, doesn't *have* access modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Access modifiers (`private` / `protected` / `public`) and the `readonly` modifier are just  Typescript constructs, they are only enforced by the compiler. This means at runtime you can both access non public members and modify readonly memebers.

Comment: is it ok to do so ? that is access private variables and modify reaodnly variables from html ?

Comment: @gopal No, I would avoid it as much as possible. Doing so might break assumptions you make in your TS code, you best avoid exploiting such holes enforcement of these modifiers.